# How to use nginx as proxy_pass to distribute requests to app containers

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Hey I'm currently a bit stupid to configure an nginx.

My goal is to get the proxy_pass following nginx configuration for my 2 REST endpoints:

- http://localhost/app-one/ping -> http://app-one:1111/ping
- http://localhost/app-two/ping -> http://app-two:2222/ping

means if I call `http://localhost/app-one/ping` from my browser, it should be forwarded to `http://app-one:1111/ping` in my docker environment

here is a greatly simplified representation of my docker and docker compose files:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  proxy:
    image: "proxy"
    build: ./nginx-data
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    environment:
    - NGINX_PORT=80
  app-one:
    image: "app-one"
    container_name: app-one
  app-two:
    image: "app-two"
    container_name: app-two
```

and here is my attempt of an nginx config which is Failed:

```
worker_processes 1;
  
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream app-one {
        server app-one:1111;
    }

    upstream app-two {
        server app-two:2222;
    }

    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    
    server {
        listen 80;
 
        location /app-one {
            proxy_pass         http://app-one:1111;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
 
        location /app-two {
            proxy_pass         http://app-two:2222;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to adjust the nginx configuration :)
In any case is there any other issue in the above, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are there 3 containers in the same docker runtime? if yes: 1) only the the reverse proxy should be exposed; 2) app-one and app-two may listen on the same port (this is optional but may help you understand what is really happening). 3) the nginx container can address the two backend applications using their service names, without leaving the docker network; 4) in conclusion, a regular proxy_pass should do the work:  `location /app-one { proxy_pass: app-one:1111 }`

Comment: it worked thx :) 
the problem seems to have been that the proxy started before the application. when I start it afterwards everything works as you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application containers must already be running when the nginx proxy is going to be started. Otherwise the nginx configuration did not works so it is not started.

To fix this problem we can adjusted the docker-compose file with **depends_on** section so that it could work as expected:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  proxy:
    image: "proxy"
    build: ./nginx-data
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    environment:
    - NGINX_PORT=80
    depends_on:
      app-one:
        condition: service_started
      app-two:
        condition: service_started
  app-one:
    image: "app-one"
    container_name: app-one
  app-two:
    image: "app-two"
    container_name: app-two
```

**Execution process:**

`docker-compose up` command will starts services in dependency order. In our example, app-one and app-two are started before proxy service starts.

`docker-compose stop` command will stops services in dependency order. In our example, proxy is stopped before app-one and app-two.